# accessing ajax.actionlink "text to display"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

if I have an ajax.actionlink

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Add Last Name", // <-- Text to display
     "AddTimeSeriesData", // <-- Action Method Name
      etc....
      @id = "link")
```

how can I access the "text to display" (the link text) in javascript?

I tried

```
$('#link').innerHTML
```

but that didn't work and doesn't seem right...
I just tried

```
console.log($('#link'));
```

and under innerHTML and innerText I got the same value I'm looking for (the link text) but when I try to do

```
console.log($('#link').innerHTML); //or innerText
```

I get "undefined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you are actually adding the id attribute (you haven't shown the full code so hard to tell if its correct). Should be something like

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Add Last Name", "AddTimeSeriesData", null, new AjaxOptions { }, new { ID = "link" })
```

Then you can access the text with

```
var displayText = $('#link').text();
```

Comment: FYI `$('#link')` returns a jQuery-wrapped DOM element, not the actual DOM element, so if you wanted to use `.innerHTML`, then it would need to be `$('#link')[0].innerHTML;` or `$('#link').get(0).innerHTML;`